# Elixir stream audio to users

Tags: streaming, elixir, html5-audio, audio-streaming

The following code streams a file to a process.
I want to stream audio/mp3
to many users who will hear it via html5 audio tag.
How can it be done via `File.stream!`?

```elixir
defmodule Test do

    def start do
        p = spawn(Test, :say, [])
        send p, {self, "a message"}
    end

    def say do
        receive do
          {from, msg} ->
            IO.puts "Process #{inspect self} says: #{msg}"
            stream_bytes = 128
            File.stream!("./song.mp3", [], stream_bytes)
            |> Enum.each(fn chunk ->
                IO.inspect chunk
            end)
            say
        end
    end
end
```

$: iex test.ex

iex(1)> Test.start

output:

<<171, 46, 254, 26, 163, 32, 178, 27, 0, 75, 17, 35, 4, 236, 51, 57, 5, 144, 154, 198, 166, 47, 62, 4, 61, 85, 67, 135, 16, 34, 82, 49, 57, 176, 131, 96, 116, 152, 232, 24, 32, 140, 220, 67, 73, 128, 165, 178, 230, 202, ...>>
<<100, 220, 156, 191, 38, 0, 161, 117, 80, 16, 102, 91, 22, 5, 8, 66, 26, 7, 193, 155, 193, 66, 198, 28, 157, 244, 65, 131, 204, 240, 5, 172, 143, 44, 173, 85, 144, 2, 157, 144, 145, 97, 200, 236, 16, 49, 149, 150, 133, 67, ...>>
<<150, 54, 37, 254, 192, 218, 218, 26, 69, 231, 88, 124, 33, 129, 169, 66, 117, 52, 214, 134, 130, 103, 85, 130, 48, 6, 144, 221, 153, 132, 8, 181, 26, 27, 83, 140, 54, 117, 149, 7, 60, 144, 237, 248, 132, 12, 210, 51, 103, 116, ...>>
<<57, 2, 143, 220, 198, 182, 22, 177, 231, 126, 187, 147, 33, 9, 1, 5, 164, 2, 36, 105, 47, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 245, 54, 51, 225, 104, 98, 1, 184, 148, 206, 50, 135, 230, 28, 50, 47, 144, 134, 53, 16, 64, 130, 192, 198, ...>>
..............

how can I use JavaScript to read this binary data and hear it via audio tag ?

Comment: Hi, small question. I got the same requirement like this. are you happy about using elixir for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a plug based web framework it should be reasonably straight forward. This is possible if you're using plug directly or if you're using it from within phoenix (which is based on plug).

Maybe a plug like this would do the trick

```elixir
defmodule Audio do
  @chunk_size 128

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def song(conn, _opts) do
    conn = conn
    |> send_chunked(200)
    |> put_resp_header("content-type", "audio/mpeg")

    File.stream!("/some/song/somewhere.mp3", [], @chunk_size)
    |> Enum.into(conn)
  end 
end
```

Maybe you want to hook up your plug to a phoenix router like this

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use MyApp.Web, :router

  get "/the_song", Audio, :song
end
```

Then in your page

```html
<audio src="/the_song">
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Comment: thank you ! it works, but throws an expection "[error] Ranch listener Plugtest.HTTP had connection process started with :cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at #PID<0.261.0> exit with reason: {{%File.Error{action: "stream", path: "./song.mp3", reason: :enoent}.." && how can I stream it like radio so all connected users will hear from the same second ? for this test I can loop the song but I want to continue to next song in the playlist

Comment: That error says that the file doesn't exist. You'll need to resolve the path - i'd suggest not using relative paths. 

As far as your actual goal, this is a step towards it but you need more. Now you're talking about a pubsub architecture. In Elixir this should be surprisingly easy. You'll want a single process that is running and holding on to the file stream, and keeps track of open connections. A GenServer will work well. As it reads chunks from the stream, it should write to each connection it knows about.

Comment: thanks again @rozap , please check related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551798