# Elixir stream to all subscribers

Tags: streaming, elixir, cowboy

I'm trying to implement a radio server in Elixir

One process is always working and reading a file (mp3) and publish to topic ":radio", currently for test purpose when it finishes it starts over

Each connection subscribes to topic ":radio"

I don't understand how to send the chunks to all subscribed connections, the connection closed after 2 or 3 chunks

```elixir
defmodule Plugtest do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def start() do
    Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http(Plugtest, [])
    {:ok, _pid} = PubSub.start_link()
    spawn(fn -> stream_from_file("./song.mp3", 128) end)
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    conn = conn
    |> send_chunked(200)
    |> put_resp_content_type("audio/mpeg")

    :ok = PubSub.subscribe(spawn(fn -> send_chunk_to_connection(conn) end), :radio)
#    File.stream!("./song.mp3", [], 128) |> Enum.into(conn) # test purpose only
  end

  defp send_chunk_to_connection(conn) do
    receive do
      {:radio_data, data} ->
        IO.inspect "* #{inspect self()} * [ #{inspect conn.owner} ] [ #{inspect data} ]"
#        Enum.into(data, conn) # not working TODO send chunk to connection
        {:ok, conn} = chunk(conn, data)
        send_chunk_to_connection(conn)
    end
  end

  defp stream_from_file(fpath, bytes) do
    File.stream!(fpath, [], bytes)
    |> Enum.each(fn chunk ->
      PubSub.publish(:radio, {:radio_data, chunk})
    end)
    stream_from_file(fpath, bytes)
  end

end
```

Stacktrace :

```
[error] Process #PID<0.274.0> raised an exception
        ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :closed}    
            (plugtest) lib/plugtest.ex:26: Plugtest.send_chunk_to_connection/1
```

dependencies :

```elixir
  defp deps do
    [{:plug, "~> 1.0"}, {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}, {:pubsub, "~> 0.0.2"}]
  end
```

edit after @maxdec comment

```elixir
defmodule Plugtest do
  import Plug.Conn

  @file_path "./song.mp3"
  @port 4000
  @chunk_size 128

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def start() do
    Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http Plugtest, [], port: @port
    {:ok, _pid} = PubSub.start_link()
    spawn fn ->
        stream_from_file(@file_path, @chunk_size)
    end
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    conn = conn
    |> send_chunked(200)
    |> put_resp_content_type("audio/mpeg")

    :ok = PubSub.subscribe(spawn(fn -> send_chunk_to_connection(conn) end), :radio)
#    File.stream!("./song.mp3", [], 128) |> Enum.into(conn) # test purpose only
    conn
  end
  defp send_chunk_to_connection(conn) do
    receive do
      {:radio_data, data} ->
        case chunk(conn, data) do
          {:ok, conn} -> send_chunk_to_connection(conn)
          {:error, err} -> IO.puts err # do nothing, as something went wrong (client disconnection or something else...)
        end
    end
  end

  defp stream_from_file(fpath, bytes) do
    File.stream!(fpath, [], bytes)
    |> Enum.each(fn chunk ->
      PubSub.publish(:radio, {:radio_data, chunk})
    end)
    stream_from_file(fpath, bytes)
  end

end
```

Comment: do I need to send unique headers to make chunked encoding working for audio via http ?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look I think there are 2 things you should fix:

1. `PlugTest` is a `Plug` so `call/2` should return `conn` (that's not your issue though). It should also blocks while waiting for events (`receive`):

```elixir
    def call(conn, _opts) do
      conn = conn
      |> send_chunked(200)
      |> put_resp_content_type("audio/mpeg")

      :ok = PubSub.subscribe(self(), :radio)
      send_chunk_to_connection(conn)
    end
```

2. In `send_chunk_to_connection` you should do:

```elixir
    defp send_chunk_to_connection(conn) do
      receive do
        {:radio_data, data} ->
          case chunk(conn, data) do
            {:ok, conn} -> send_chunk_to_connection(conn)
            {:error, err} -> IO.puts err; conn # do nothing, as something went wrong (client disconnection or something else...)
          end
      end
    end
```

Comment: first of all, thanks, its not working, I changed call/2, didn't understand what to do at send_chunk_to_connection/1, appended the code above

Comment: tried, got "closed", I don't get 2#send_chunk_to_connection#{:ok, conn}, where is the Enum.into that send data to connection ? (also, edited code above)

Comment: @JimWest: try my new edit: subscribe the process of the current connect and block as long as you keep receiving events. Unfortunately I can't test myself at the moment

Comment: its okay, thanks for helping, anyway ":cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at #PID<0.276.0> exit with reason: {{%Protocol.UndefinedError{description: "", protocol: Enumerable..." still I don't understand where is the line that sends the data to the connection (Enum.into?)